# Rosenkreuz and Guilderstein have Fled

Tags: riddle, cipher, knowledge

You are the powerful prince El-Tham of Merkand, and to display your power and largesse, you allow a number of foreign alchemists and mystics to inhabit your court. However, this morning the rooms of two of them were empty, the occupants having apparently departed in the middle of the night. Later, a sizable quantity of gold was found to be missing from your treasury! These two men are suspected of the deed, and a search was made of their remaining effects in order to find any clues as to where they have gone. Nothing of note was found, save a scrap of parchment with some cryptic symbols on it. Can you, in your royal wisdom, decipher the document and find if it has any clues to these thieves’ whereabouts?

[image: 1]]
KVJIVUWQJFWHLQWXYSJIJH
IWMKNZFKMSMGNFCKTTBLRCL
WZBVNPCWJYIVXVNNVNSTM
KYGPHZOLPPDCYTYGELXTVCN

Comment: Is the mis-spelling of 'Rosencrantz and Guildenstern' an intentional part of the puzzle?

Comment: Perhaps, perhaps not. If it were, I certainly wouldn't want to tell you, now would I? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Additional progress:

Having read f"'s spoilers for the first three rows, I find that the fourth row is

> a Vigenere cipher with the key `BRIEF`, reading (spaces added) `VITRIOL OF THE PRIME FOOL`.

Furthermore, the fifth row is

> a Vigenere cipher with the key `SKULL`, reading (spaces added) `SOMEWHERE ELSE IN OUR MIDST`.

Also

> `El-Tham` and `Merkand` are, respectively, anagrams of `Hamlet` and `Denmark`.

Also

> The names Rosenkreuz and Guilderstein apparently invoke Rosicrucian and possibly Masonic elements in connection with alchemy.  Consider *Die warhhaffte und vollkommene Bereitung des Philosophischen Steins der Brüderschaft aus dem Orden des Gülden-und Rosen-Creutzes (The True and Complete Preparation of the Philosopher's Stone by the Brotherhood from the Order of the Golden and Rosy Cross)*, for example.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosicrucianism.

I offer a solution

> Helsingør, known in Shakespeare's day as Elsinore (taken from "somewhere **else in our** midst")

Comment: Nice work! Now the question is- can you tell where they have gone?

Comment: @PatrickN nah, I haven't got that far yet :-(

Comment: Well, you're getting quite close, so keep at it!

Comment: @PatrickN I've added a proposed solution.  Is it right?

Comment: Yup! Great work

Comment: @PatrickN thanks.  I owe a lot to f": I didn't even know what a Vigenere cipher was before I saw this puzzle.

Answer (score 12):

Some progress:

The first row is

> a pigpen cipher reading `the key is in a name`.

The second row is

> a Vigenere cipher with the key "rose", reading `three gems reduce the rest`.

The third row is

> a Vigenere cipher with the key "four", reading `distill the spirit of humor`.